# Buttons are not working on bottom of iPhone5

Tags: iphone, ios, camera, uibutton, iphone-5

In my iPhone app,I have used an overlay on the camera.
I have 3 buttons on bottom-capture,flash,cancel
All working fine on iPhone 3.5" devices.I have changed the Y position for all according to iPhone 5.Buttons are at proper positions.But none of them are working

I have place brake point to each actions,they are not being called.
Trying for last 3 hours-but could not figure out the issue.

Any help ?

**EDIT**
I am adding all my buttons to the overlay in this

```
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
  if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
   }
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried it with AutoSizing?

Comment: post some code or screenshot :)

Comment: @DaleeDavis No..this is a seperate class
I am calling it in my camera view's viewDidLoad as - self.imagepicker.cameraOverlayView = overlay;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding your buttons are out of it's parent view's bounds. Hence they are not responding to touch events. You need to make sure that all buttons are in parent view's bounds. You need to increase parent view's bounds area to accomodate buttons. Try increasing height of parent view of buttons.

Comment: how to increase that parent views bounds ?

Comment: Change it's frame. Set some extra height.

Comment: Try logging overlay view & button in viewDidAppear. Check height of overlay & button's y origin. Make sure that button's y origin + it's height should not be greater than overlay's height.

Comment: It's good to use auto-resizing when you want your app to work on 3.5" & 4" display. It allows you to manage your views/subviews positions & sizes very easily.

Comment: Man..have you ever faced a problem while moving from Wifi to 3G network..my app is not getting reconnected switching from Wifi to 3G

Please look my question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15314540/network-error-while-switching-from-wifi-to-3g

Comment: I looked into it, but I can't help with it. I haven't faced this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Well i have been through this issue..you will have to change the frames for `OverlayView` Camera..if you are adding a `UIView` then change its frames when you allocating it or else if you are using `Image Picker Controller` then change its frame size.

This should help you.

Let me know if have any queries.

Comment: I have created a class for overlay,and adding these buttons in that.please read my edit..

Comment: Ok the button's code should be fine..we need the code where in you alloc this UIview(overlay) and set its frame:)