# textfieldshouldclear: not invoked by UITextfield

Tags: ios, uitextfield, popover, uitextfielddelegate

I am trying to invoke `-(BOOL) textFieldShouldClear:(UITextField *)textField` when UITextField's clear button is tapped. I have already set my delegate and UITextField's other delegate's methods are being called correctly, except this one. Clear Button is set to "is always visible" in nib file.

**EDIT**

FYI I am showing [FPPopover](https://github.com/50pixels/FPPopover) when textfield's text is changed. if I tap on clear button without showing popover, clear button works fine. But if I try to tap it when popover is being displayed, delegate method is not called.

**Code Snippet**

```
-(BOOL) textFieldShouldClear:(UITextField *)textField
{
    return YES;
}

- (IBAction)didChangeScripText:(id)sender {

    NSString *text = isPortrait ? symbolTextField.text : landsymbolTextfield.text;

    if(scripList.count == 0)
    {
        if([Logs sharedManager].scripData.count > 0)
            [self extractScrips];
        else
            return;
    }

    //        SAFE_ARC_RELEASE(popover);
//        popover=nil;

        //the controller we want to present as a popover
        if(controller == nil)
            controller = [[scripComboViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];

        if(controller.scripListFiltered.count > 0)
            [controller.scripListFiltered removeAllObjects];

        controller.delegate = self;
        if(popover == nil){
            popover = [[FPPopoverController alloc] initWithViewController:controller];
            popover.tint = FPPopoverDefaultTint;
        }

    controller.scripListFiltered = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[scripList filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[c] %@",text]]];
    NSLog(@"array is: %@",controller.scripListFiltered);

    if(controller.scripListFiltered.count == 0)
    {
        [popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
        return;
    }
        //decide contentsize and arrow dir based on tableview height

        if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
        {
            popover.contentSize = CGSizeMake(300, 500);
        }
        else {
            popover.contentSize = CGSizeMake(200, 200);
        }

        //sender is the uitextfield
    float height = isPortrait ? portTable.frame.size.height : landTable.frame.size.height;
    if(height > 0)
        popover.arrowDirection = FPPopoverArrowDirectionDown;
    else
        popover.arrowDirection = FPPopoverArrowDirectionUp;

    if(![popover isModalInPopover])
        [popover presentPopoverFromView:sender];

    [controller reloadTable];

}
```

What is going wrong? Can anyone tell me. Thanks.

Comment: @Rahul it appears but does not highlight on tap.

Comment: Then probably your textfield is crossing bounds of it's superview. Somehow some part(including clear button) of your textfield is may be crossing parent view's bounds(frame). Check my answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15331725/buttons-are-not-working-on-bottom-of-iphone5/15331793#15331793

Comment: post a snippet of code .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually problem is due to **FPPopover**. When it receives touch event outside its view, it dismisses itself, and no interaction with outside controls is possible at that time. So if tap clear button, it will be used to dismiss the pop up and then I am able to use clear button. Thats all.